# How do I point RVM to my Homebrew Ruby dir?

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew

I installed Ruby 1.9.2 using homebrew, then installed RVM.

I want to point RVM to the version I have in my Cellar folder. How can I make `rvm --default 1.9.1` point to the one in Cellar without having to reinstall it again using RVM?

Comment: Homebrew itself suggests that you use RVM or Cinderella to manage Ruby environments: `brew info ruby` will show you this message `[...]Consider using RVM or Cinderella to manage Ruby environments: * RVM: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/ * Cinderella: http://www.atmos.org/cinderella/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it and get the right behavior.

RVM works within its own directory when running as a single-user's sandbox. Any Ruby it controls will exist in your `~/.rvm` directory.

Anything outside of RVM's control will be considered the `system` setting, and it will be up to you to manage whether that is the regular Ruby installed in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or in `/opt` or wherever.

In my opinion, you should let RVM manage the Ruby installations. It is very slick and has rapidly become the favored way to manage Ruby development environments on Linux and Mac OS.

You could try creating aliases from the Cellar folder to the appropriate place in the `~/.rvm`, but RVM modifies some things during its install process, such as `gem`, which would not be done in the Homebrew-installed folder, and would cause RVM's gem support to break for that Ruby version.